# Strange Play Framework 2.2 exceptions after trying to add MySQL / slick

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a Play 2.2 application, and things have gone a bit south on me since I've tried adding my DB layer.

Below are my `build.sbt` dependencies. As you can see I use `mysql-connector-java` and `play-slick`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.26",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.5.0.8",
  "com.aetrion.flickr" % "flickrapi" % "1.1"
)
```

My `application.conf` has some similarly simple DB stuff in it:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDb"
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.user="root"
db.default.pass=""
```

This is what it looks like when my Play server starts:

```
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\bbq\cats\in\space
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDb
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

So, it appears that Play can connect to the MySQL DB just fine (I think). However, I get this exception when I make any request to my server:

```
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lscala/concurren
t/ExecutionContext;
        at play.core.Invoker$.<init>(Invoker.scala:24) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at play.core.Invoker$.<clinit>(Invoker.scala) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution$Implicits$.defaultContext$lzycompu
te(Execution.scala:7) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution$Implicits$.defaultContext(Executio
n.scala:6) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution$.<init>(Execution.scala:10) ~[play
_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution$.<clinit>(Execution.scala) ~[play_
2.10.jar:2.2.0]
```

The odd thing is that the 2nd request (to the exact same URL, same controller, no changes) comes back with a different error:

```
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class play.api.libs.concurr
ent.Execution$
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.handleAction$1(Play
DefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:194) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(Pla
yDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:169) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageRecei
ved(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[netty-http-pipelining.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived
(HttpContentDecoder.java:108) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:29
6) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessage
Received(FrameDecoder.java:459) ~[netty-3.6.5.Final.jar:na]
```

The URL / controller that I'm requesting just renders a static web page and doesn't do anything of any significance. It was working just fine before I started adding my DB layer. [I'm rather stuck.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDOJu.jpg) Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I'm using Scala 2.10.2, Play 2.2.0, and MySQL Server 5.6.14.0 (community edition).

Comment: Which Scala version are you using? It should be 2.10.2

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.10.2: `Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_4
5).`

Comment: Looks like some kind of version incompability, if some library would pull in an older akka version for example, but your dependency list looks like it doesn't.

Comment: Second error is a Javaism because there was an exception in a static block.  That part's a red herring, anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out. I feel like a bit of a dolt, but I'll post it here since it may be useful to someone else:

During earlier work on my project, I was experimenting with other potential libraries for various things: Mongo, BSON converters, etc. Of course, while experimenting, I was adding them to my IDE's project library dependencies (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12). Naturally, IntelliJ was downloading the JARs and placing them into my project's lib directory. However, after settling on the libraries that I wanted to use and removing the unnecessary ones from my project dependencies, IntelliJ *did NOT* delete/clean out the unused JARs from my project's lib directory. This resulted in a whole bunch of unnecessary JARs being in there, some of which presumably conflicted with the SBT libs.

In short: **I cleaned out my Play project's lib directory, double-checked my project's library dependencies in the IDE, and re-imported only the JARs that I really needed.**

Comment: Looks like a problem with dependencies? I have the same issue I just can't figure it out.